# 'Session.getConfig()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, arcore

I am new to Android developer, I am trying to build a simple app on my own using ARCore. Currently I have difficulty using the Depth function. In my case, user press a Button will activate the check_depth_support function, this the check_depth_support funtion:

```
public void check_depth_support() {
    Config config = session.getConfig();
    boolean isDepthSupported = session.isDepthModeSupported(Config.DepthMode.AUTOMATIC);

    if (isDepthSupported)
    {
        config.setDepthMode(Config.DepthMode.AUTOMATIC);
        checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Depth not support on this devices",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        checked = false;
    }
    session.configure(config);
}
```

And when I press the button, I get an error: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.ar.core.Config com.google.ar.core.Session.getConfig()' on a null object reference"
I'm following [This Guide](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/developer-guide)
I also tried following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/session-config#create_a_session), to turn above code into:

```
    private Session session; // Global

public void check_depth_support() {
try {
    session = new Session(this);
} catch (UnavailableArcoreNotInstalledException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnavailableApkTooOldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnavailableSdkTooOldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnavailableDeviceNotCompatibleException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Config config = new Config(session);
boolean isDepthSupported = session.isDepthModeSupported(Config.DepthMode.AUTOMATIC);
if (isDepthSupported)
{
    config.setDepthMode(Config.DepthMode.AUTOMATIC);
    checked = true;
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Depth not support on this devices",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    checked = false;
}
session.configure(config);
}
```

But its still not working, can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: `session` is null here . debug the initialization code that's second block of code in your question and check if you get any exception during initialization .

Comment: The app still crash when I press the button, in the Logcat I got
`com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException
at com.example.prototype2.MainActivity.check_depth_support(MainActivity.java:295)`
And the line 295 is
`session = new Session(this);`

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the above error disappeared after I followed the example in [Hello AR Sample](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java)